# Using 得 with past particle 了

Tags: translation, grammar, adverbs

I tried to translate this sentence:

> The man cleaned the bathroom cleanly.

I thought it would be:

> 他把卫生间打扫得干净了。

but my Chinese friends said that this is a wrong sentence.
I am wondering,

1. Why is this grammatically wrong?
2. How should I fix this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say

- "他把卫生间打扫干净了"  The man have cleaned the bathroom.
- "他把卫生间打扫得很干净" The man cleaned the bathroom cleanly.

「得」字的用法：

1.覺得。feel.

2.介詞。preposition. After verb or adj. to express the result or state.

- After verb. Ex：跑得快、說得很動聽。
- After adj. Ex：美得冒泡。

Answer (score 1):

If you add 得 to the sentence, 打扫得 is like an adverb, so you should not include 得.
打扫 = verb
干净了 = cleanly

You can fix the sentence by just removing the "得".

他把卫生间打扫干净了